# What's the meaning of 'soup' in jsoup and Beautiful Soup?

Tags: beautifulsoup, jsoup

What's the meaning of "soup" in jsoup and Beautiful Soup, and why it is called "soup"?

Answer (score 15):

It's [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), and is named after so-called ['tag soup'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup), which refers to 
"syntactically or structurally incorrect HTML written for a web page", from the Wikipedia definition.

jsoup is the Java version of Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 1):

According to wiki "Beautiful Soup is a Python library for parsing HTML documents (including having malformed markup, i.e. non-closed tags, so named after Tag soup)."

Those were named after [Tag soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup)

Reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup is used for web-scraping and a great tool for extracting information from large unstructured data. As a Python library used for pulling data from HTML, XML, and other markup language files, Beautiful Soup can extract articles and content and turn it into a Python list or dictionary.